# Worklight 6 - Disable GCM in mobile applications

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working in an application with IBM Worklight 6.2 and application uses push notification. But now we want to migrate the Android app to FCM. The point is the worklight lib is calling the GCM, and showing that dialog with "Failed to register in GCM", because I`ve removed everything with GCM from my app.

**Is there a way to tell worklight to disable GCM?**

I dont want to let the GCM classes in my project useless just to serve the worklight and not show that stupid alert to my users.

I have looked to this [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/t_ac_client_nogcm_api.html) from IBM, but I didn't find any `gcmProjectId`

Comment: Try this: In res/xml/config.xml find 'feature name="Push"' and introduce a "param onload false" and see if that fixes your problem. Like so:

<feature name="Push">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.Push" />
        <param name="onload" value="false" />
    </feature>

Comment: It didn`t work mate :( but thanks for your help